# method that returns message according to criteria

Tags: vb.net, string, console-application

I have a situation in which a method should return two messages if there is an exception in try, catch block and it should return a single success message if there is no exception.

I'm calling this method in a different class and assigning its result to a `string`. I can concatenate the exception method and send it as a single message to this class. But, i have to split this message again.

Is there any way to split a string message?

sample code:

```
public class sendMessage
    sub main()
        method()
    end sub

    public function method() as string
        try
            ------------
            if response isnot nothing
                message= "success"
            end if
       catch
           message="failure"+" "
           message+=ex.tostring()
       end try
       return message
    end function 
end class


public class invokeMessage
    sub main()
        dim ob as new sendMessage
        dim message = ob.method()
        dim messageStatus=? ------------this can be success or failure
        dim messageException ----------- this has exception message in case of failure
    end sub
end class
```

Comment: Which language is this in, you have tagged 3, and have not code blocked your code..

Comment: The lack of indentation and naming conventions really doesn't help either.

Comment: That was a fun edit ;)

Comment: if you need two reurn 2 values i'll recommend you to use out arguments

Comment: or just use split with a given separator

Comment: Unless you're specifically using the "success" string for something else, why not just have the method return `String.Empty` for success and the error message for failure?  Then you can check whether or not the return value == `String.Empty` and handle accordingly.

Comment: It is a very bad practice to box exceptions like this. You are essentially going back 15 years in the past, it worked exactly like this in VB6 at that time (sort of). Problem with this - you lose valuable information - the stack trace, so troubleshooting this kind of errors becomes problematic. If after reading this, you still wanna do it - nothing can stop you in today's development world.

Comment: @Neolisk i m going to update it in my code. Thanks for valuable suggestion.

Comment: @LexWebb i m doing it in a console application in vb.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to return multiple values from the function, then:

1 - Define a return type

```
public class MyReturnResult
{
    public bool IsException;
    public string Message;
}

public MyReturnResult MyMethod()
{
    try
    {
       ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return new MyReturnResult() {IsException = true, Message = e.ToString()};
    }
    // can be inside try
    return new MyReturnResult() {IsException = false, Message = "Ok"};
}
```

2 - Use famous GetLastError theme

```
public string LastMessage;

public bool MyMethod()
{
    try
    {
       ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LastMessage = e.ToString();
        return true;
    }
    LastMessage = "Ok";
    return false; // no exception
}
```

3 - Use `out` parameters

```
// or make bool function and string out parameter
public string MyMethod(out bool isException)
{
    try
    {
       ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        isException = true;
        return e.ToString();
    }
    isException = false;
    return "Ok";
}
```

---

In your case you may define *special string* (to example, `"blablablaOk"` or with `null` value) to indicate *no exception* case, otherwise it would indicate what there was exception and would contain *different from that* exception message.

```
public string MyMethod()
{
    try
    {
       ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return e.ToString();
    }
    return "blablablaOk";
}
```

and then you check

```
if(MyMethod() == "blablablaOk")
{
    // no exception
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class sendMessage
    sub main()
        method()
    end sub

    public function method() as string
        try
            ------------
            if response isnot nothing
            message= "success"
            end if
       catch
           message="failure"+" "
           message+=ex.tostring()
       end try
       return message
    end function 
end class


public class invokeMessage
    sub main()
        dim ob as new sendMessage
        dim message = ob.method()
        if message.contains(separator)
            dim messages() as string = message.split(separator) // array of 2 elements with "failure" + "rest of the message"
   end sub
end class
```